# Laravel Filament admin panel Manage User Tokens

Tags: laravel, laravel-filament

How can i display  User Access Tokens and preform operations such as delete them ?
I have tried

```
Forms\Components\Repeater::make("tokens")->schema([
     Forms\Components\TextInput::make('tokens.name')
]),
```

but it doesn't show the Tokens

Answer (score 0):

You must set the relationship and the input doesn't need the relationship name again, e.g.:

```php
Forms\Components\Repeater::make('tokens')
                         ->relationship('tokens')
                         ->schema([
                              Forms\Components\TextInput::make('name')
                         ])
```